# What are examples of epic refereeing?

Tags: publications, peer-review, paper-submission

From time to time a paper is submitted that has (at least) one of the following characteristics :

- extreme length
- technical tour de force
- obfuscated/confusing wording

> What are examples in your area where it took a mammoth effort from the anonymous referee to get the paper eventually accepted, and were said paper became an important milestone ?
>
> Was that benevolent work later recognized in a somewhat non-anonymous fashion ?